# "process.currentDirectoryPath()" function is not changing the path and my python file doesn't get executed through swift code

Tags: python, swift, macos

I am working on a way to execute a python script through swift in a MacOS application in Xcode. I am using a Process class to execute the python script. So when I am trying to change the process directory using process.currentDirectoryPath() to point it to the python file in system.
But I am unable to change it as it throws an error in command module, saying unable to find the python file

```
     let process = Process()
     process.launchPath = "/usr/local/bin/python"
     process.currentDirectoryPath = "\(NSHomeDirectory())/Downloads/<pyhton-file>"
     process.arguments = ["recognize_video.py --detector face_detection_model --embedding-model openface_nn4.small2.v1.t7 --recognizer output/recognizer.pickle --le output/le.pickle"]
     do {
        try process.run()
     }
     catch let error{
         print(error.localizedDescription)
     }
```

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'recognize_video.py --detector face_detection_model --embedding-model openface_nn4.small2.v1.t7 --recognizer output/recognizer.pickle --le output/le.pickle': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This is the output I am getting.
Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems. First:

> ```
> process.currentDirectoryPath = "\(NSHomeDirectory())/Downloads/<pyhton-file>"
> ```

The current directory path must be set to a *directory,* not to the path of a file.

Second:

> ```
> process.arguments = ["recognize_video.py --detector face_detection_model ..."]
> ```

The arguments must be passed as separate array elements:

```
 process.arguments = ["recognize_video.py", "--detector", "face_detection_model", ... ]
```

Unlike the shell (which executes the commands which you type in the Terminal), `Process` does *not* separate the arguments before passing them to the process to be executed.